# Look for a variable column header and insert a formula in the column under it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following, without success.

I have two tabs, Counts and Input. what I need to do is to insert a formula that is basically a vlookup from the file codes in tab one to see that the codes generated every day (in tab 2) are matching them in the correct date.

[image]
my code so far does this:
ask to input the date that needs to be "update" = matched in tab 1. this part works and the macro finds the correct date. Now, what I am struggling with is to tell to the macro:
from the date you found, offset one row and insert the formula  for all the non empty rows in the lookup column.

hereby my code. I think I am doing something wrong in the definition of such range, since is variable.
 Thanks for all your help!

```
enter code here
Sub Macro2()

 Macro2 Macro

 Dim myValue As Date
 myValue = InputBox("Please enter the date you want to update")
 Sheets("Count").Range("A1").Value = myValue

Dim ra As Range
Dim date1 As Date
date1 = Range("A1")

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:=date1 _
                    , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , LookAt:=xlPart _
                    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                    , SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                    , MatchCase:=False _
                    , SearchFormat:=False)

     If ra Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Not found")

     Else

    'MsgBox (ra.Address)


     Dim rws As Range
     rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

     Range(ra.Offset(1, 0) & rws).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B3,'Input'!$B:$B,1,FALSE),"""")"

     End If
     End Sub
```

Comment: *insert the formula for all the non empty rows in the lookup column.* - Can you clarify this? Do you want to replace every cell in this column that has a value in it?

Comment: hi, I mean to insert the formula under the cell I lookup. So the lookup value is a date in my case. I see, that the title is confusing. I will edit it!

Comment: So if I am correct, you want the cell below the date you find, to be replaced with this formula, regardless of what is already in that cell. And that is all the action you need?

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that you dim rws as range, but then try to assign a row number to it. A range holds a cell or a number of cells, but a row number is a numeric value. Therefore it will fail. Dim it as `Long` instead so it can hold a numeric value.

Secondly you try to offset your found cell by one, and then add the last row to it. If this is an attempt to use the whole range, this is not how it is done. The `Offset` property will return the value of the cell by default, not the cell itself, unless specified with `.Address` or anything of the sort. Also, you cannot assign a singular value or formula to a range at one go. This will have to be done with a loop instead.

Below code is my approximation to what you will need, if you answer my question in the comments I can refine this:

```
Sub Macro2()

 Dim myValue As Date
 myValue = InputBox("Please enter the date you want to update")
 Sheets("Count").Range("A1").Value = myValue

Dim ra As Range
Dim date1 As Date
date1 = Range("A1")

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:=date1 _
                    , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , LookAt:=xlPart _
                    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                    , SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                    , MatchCase:=False _
                    , SearchFormat:=False)

     If ra Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Not found")

         Else

        'MsgBox (ra.Address)


         Dim rws As Long
         Dim cel As Range

         rws = Cells(Rows.Count, ra.Column).End(xlUp).Row
         For Each cel In Range(Cells(ra.Offset(1, 0).Row, ra.Column), Cells(rws, ra.Column))
              If cel <> "" Then cel.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B" & (cel.Row - 2) & ",'Input'!$B:$B,1,FALSE),"""")"
         Next cel
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it if it works. also thanks a lot for explaining the mistakes, really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, make sure to backup your data, in case it doesn't work as expected. As stated, this is an approximation and might not be exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi @Plutian, it works partially! what it does now is just substituting the formula in the cell of the date and not in the entire column.

Comment: What this should do is loop over the entire column of the found cell, and replace all non-blank cells with this formula. Is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: yes! so in the foulmula is b3 as lookup value, and then should go to b4 and so on. Basically column B of tab1 is alway static, while every day new entries are generated in tab 2. Yes, so every cell should contain that formula. does it make it more clear?

Comment: I have amended my answer, it now uses the row it is on as a reference, and subtracts 2 to have it start at B row 3 instead of row 5 (if I'm correct looking at your data). Using this the formula is amended for every cell. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. The formula still appears in the first cell under the date only. In addition, now the formula always only looks at column B:B in the tab two, however the columns change as the date on the header changes.

Comment: It will only replace cells that were previously filled. If the rest of your column is empty, it will not be replaced. Filling the entire column with this formula is a bad idea. Also you previously stated the column should be fixed...

Comment: You have two issues here, the range to be filled, which I can adapt with above code. But having the formula change dynamically is a new issue altogether, perhaps it is best you start a new question for that.

Comment: I understand. I have updated the image of what the final result should look like. the yellow column is the fixed one, however the column inside the vlookup formula is changing as the data are entered in a new column (under a new date) in tab 2. But I understand that are two different problems. Thanks for making a start!